# Crontab can't execute script directly in container environment

Tags: bash, docker, cron

I present to you the following dilemma I execute my script manually and it works well, see next line for example:

```sh
docker exec -ti backup_subversion sh -c "/tmp/my_script.sh"
```

But when I attempt to schedule the process this line is just skipped.

- I have tried to execute just a touch command and it too is ignored.
- I have tried to execute as root, same problem.
- I have tried to execute in another docker environment: same problem.

My OS is Centos 7.

In this script for example the bug part who will crash :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Create a container.
docker run -d --name=backup_subversion \
-v /subversion/dump:/var/dump \
--net my_network my_server.domaine.com/subversion/billy:1.9

# I copy a script.
docker cp tools_subversion_dump.sh backup_subversion:/tmp

# This line is ignore since crontab exec.
docker exec -ti backup_subversion sh -c "/tmp/tools_subversion_dump.sh"
```

Thank you in advance for your answers because it's a mystery to me.

Comment: can you clarify that last part, what do you mean by `the bug part who will crash`? is this the script that doesn't work when you schedule it?

Comment: Yes when i schedule the script the last line is not executed ; but manually it's fine.

Comment: please try and remove the `-t` option and if it fails again also remove the `-t` option. did this solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you VERY much dude ; it's work ;) I remove the -t option and it is solve now.

Comment: Great! happy ut solved it, I'll formalate an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you used the `-it` options that only apply to an interactive shell rather then a pseudo one like the one used in scripts as referenced in the question